# Only default argument working

Tags: c++, qt, default-value, function-calls

Header file:

```
MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0, ColumnHelper column_helper = ColumnHelper() );
```

`.cpp` file:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent, ColumnHelper column_helper)
```

Usage:

```
SpreadColumnHelper column_helper;
MainWindow w(0,column_helper);
```

`SpreadColumnHelper` is the derived class of `ColumnHelper`.

But only the default `ColumnHelper` class is obtained in `Main()`.

**EDIT**

I want the derived class to be passed in `MainWindow()` but the base class is passed. How can I pass the derived class?

Comment: How can you tell the difference? Both are default constructed.

Comment: I did not understand.

Comment: `SpreadColumnHelper column_helper;` uses the default constructor, as does the default argument. Hence, it will be difficult to tell the difference.

Comment: @dd2 You are object slicing there. If you want derived to be passed you need to use pointers...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is object slicing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the parameter of `MainWindow` is declared as an immediate object of type `ColumnHelper`, it will always be an object of type `ColumnHelper`. It is impossible for it to somehow change its type, regardless of what you pass as an argument.

Trying to pass a `SpreadColumnHelper` as an argument will only cause it to get "sliced" to its `ColumnHelper` base subobject. That `ColumnHelper` object will be received by `MainWindow` (which is exactly what you observe).

If you want your `column_helper` parameter to behave *polymorphically*, you have to declare it as either a pointer or a reference to `ColumnHelper`, e.g.

```
MainWindow(QWidget *parent, ColumnHelper &column_helper)
```

or maybe

```
MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0, const ColumnHelper &column_helper = ColumnHelper())
```

Note that providing a temporary object as a default argument is only possible if the parameter is declared as a const reference.

Answer (score 1):

You sure that the default constructor of **SpreadColumnHelper** has different return value with default constructor of `ColumnHelper`? I guess that because these two default constructor has same realization.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that the second argument to the function is passed by value.  When passing an object of derived type, a `ColumnHelper` object is created, using only `ColumnHelper` parts of the supplied object and this is what the function receives.   This is described as object slicing - a copy of only part of the passed object is received by the function.

Change the second argument to be a `const` reference (a non-`const` reference does not play well with default arguments specified as a value).

Comment: Thanks, for the clarification. It solved my problem. sorry, could not accept 2 answers unfortunately.